# logger: одновременный вывод в консоль и в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, логирование

Нужно логирование и в консоль, и в файл, но если указать, что надо логировать в файл, то логи в консоль не выводятся.

К примеру такой код:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(format = '[%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s]: %(message)s', datefmt='%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S', level=logging.INFO)

    logging.info('Info message??))')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Всё нормально, логи выводятся в консоль.

А вот если указать `filename`, то логи пишутся только в файл:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(filename = 'Log.log', format = '[%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s]: %(message)s', datefmt='%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S', level=logging.INFO)

    logging.info('Info message??))')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Хотелось бы вывод и туда(консоль) и туда(файл), как это можно сделать?

Comment: Сделать два logging.basicConfig для файла и для консоли не помогает?

Comment: @Pashok, это как? Можно пример? И не будет ли это в ущерб скорости?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import logging

file_log = logging.FileHandler('Log.log')
console_out = logging.StreamHandler()

logging.basicConfig(handlers=(file_log, console_out), 
                    format='[%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s]: %(message)s', 
                    datefmt='%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logging.info('Info message??))')
```